# Why is Data.List.genericLength implemented as a right fold?

Tags: haskell

`genericLength` is implemented, as of base 4.12, as:

```hs
genericLength           :: (Num i) => [a] -> i
{-# NOINLINE [1] genericLength #-}
genericLength []        =  0
genericLength (_:l)     =  1 + genericLength l

{-# RULES
  "genericLengthInt"     genericLength = (strictGenericLength :: [a] -> Int);
  "genericLengthInteger" genericLength = (strictGenericLength :: [a] -> Integer);
 #-}

strictGenericLength     :: (Num i) => [b] -> i
strictGenericLength l   =  gl l 0
                        where
                           gl [] a     = a
                           gl (_:xs) a = let a' = a + 1 in a' `seq` gl xs a'
```

which is basically a `foldr`, except that for `Int` and `Integer` it performs a `foldl'` instead.

Why does it not use `foldl'` in all cases? Doesn't `foldr` build up large thunks for long lists?

Comment: It does not *per se* builds a large thunk of long lists, that depends on the `Num` implementation. For example one could implement `(+)` in such a way that it sometimes only has to look to the first element, and due too lazyness, it could thus terminate the before evaluating the entire list.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`genericLength` is implemented with things like Peano numbers in mind:

```
data Peano = Zero | Succ Peano
```

Numbers using this representation can be non-strict, so an operation like `genericLength [1..] > 5` returns True instead of failing to terminate.

For most other reasonable implementations of Num, the foldr in `genericLength` does indeed cause the problems you mention.